# Using Catch Blocks to Return, Bad Idea?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

This may be a stupid question, but I'm interested in the performance of using try/catch blocks.

I have a DataGrid that assigns a Converter to the background property of a DataGridCell. In the converter, I compare the value of this year's data to last year's data; if this year's data is > 3%, I return a Green background; if it's > 0% and < 3%, I return a Yellow; and if it's < 0%, I return Red:

```
string x = values[0].ToString().Replace("$", "").Replace(",", ""); //This year's number
string y = values[1].ToString().Replace("$", "").Replace(",", ""); //Last year's

result = (((float.Parse(x) * 100) / float.Parse(y)) - 1) * 100;

if (result >= 3)
    return Brushes.LimeGreen;
else if (result >= 0)
    return Brushes.Yellow;
else
    return Brushes.Red;
```

However, in some cases, the cell will NOT have a value of last year; as you can guess, dividing by 0 (or some text as the Converter seems to receive when the Cell is empty) is a pretty bad idea and will throw an exception. So, I decided the easiest way to deal with this was:

```
try
{
    result = (((float.Parse(x) * 100) / float.Parse(y)) - 1) * 100;
}
catch
{
    return Brushes.DarkOrange;
}
```

So if the exception is thrown (whereby there is no value to compare to), return an Orange and call it a day. (edit: yes, I do wish to return an Orange when there is no value to compare to.

Currently, I can predict that it will only happen to one row of data for now, so it only catches about 10 cells when it's populated. But as the future goes on, it has the possibility of having it happen more times.

The try/catch block is the easiest and quickest way to handle this(as far as I can tell), but it is obviously not the only way, especially since I know the error. So Is using a try/catch block a bad idea in this case? And by bad idea, I mean will it slow performance since it is iterated over many, many times? Given that I know what the error will be, should I preempt it, or is using a try/catch block fine?

Comment: This is a very very bad idea. Google articles on Best Practices for .Net Exception Handling.  Worrying about performance of exceptions should be setting off flashing red lights and warning sirens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bad idea. It's not an exceptional situation, so don't handle it like it's one. The fact that you're worried about performance and exception handling is a smell that you're doing something wrong. There is a really simple way to handle this, so I don't even see why you ever thought to instead handle it using exception handling.

Yes, it will impact your performance but that shouldn't be your concern here. Your concern should be what is the clearest way to write this logic, and using exceptions is clearly not the way.

Here's that simple way:

```
double value;
if(!Float.TryParse(y, out value) || value == 0f) {
    return Brushes.DarkOrange;
}
else {
    double result = (((float.Parse(x) * 100) / value) - 1) * 100;
    if (result >= 3) {
        return Brushes.LimeGreen;
    }
    else if (result >= 0) {
       return Brushes.Yellow;
    }
    else {
        return Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question wasn't how to solve this, but if a try catch reduces performance.

Comment: Oh, I know I can do this; I honestly hacked the try/catch together quickly to fix the issue since I was doing a bunch of different things. Now that I'm going back through it, I was just interested in the usage of try/catch and so I posted. As I said, I'm well aware this isn't the only way to solve my problem -- nor do I declare that I do HAVE a problem.

Comment: @Quickhorn: Okay, allow me to elaborate. This is a terrible idea. It's not an exceptional situation, so it's a bad way to handle it. Worrying about performance and exception handling is a smell that something is really wrong. My "What?" is a shorthand way of answering the question: yes, this is a bad idea.

Comment: I can see that. And your elaboration actually answers his question.

Comment: Right, this is exactly what I'm looking for Jason. Maybe I asked wrong, but my general idea was not that I had a problem that needed solving, but which solution is the best overall? Try/catch was quick, but it seemed dirty. So I was wondering if it indeed was dirty or, in a simple case like this, can be it considered suitable, albeit hacky.

Comment: I also wish to add that I'm NOT worried about performance for the program, but was interested in the performance aspects of using try/catch in simple cases.

Comment: I've switched my downvote now that you've edited your post. I hope that explains my initial downvote well enough.

Answer (score 7):

In general, exceptions should be used for truly exceptional cases - cases which are not expected. In a situation like this, where you're well aware that there could be no prior year, I'd suggest using simple `if()` checks to return your default values.

To answer your performance question, Microsoft [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009.aspx) that "Throwing exceptions can negatively impact performance".

Answer (score 3):

The try catch has one of the worst performances on the .Net framework. Look [here](http://www.chinhdo.com/20080226/try-catch-blocks-performance/) When an exception is raised the stacktrace has to be checked to find in which method there is a catch for that specific exception and this is a costly operation.

Never do things like that with exceptions if you have performance in mind (and I would say even if you don't have performance on mind).

Comment: Interesting; did not know that it called the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

Catch statements should only be used for catching Exceptions..Not altering the program flow, So to answer your question, yes this is a bad idea. 
And I can't imagine it to be performant, because a new Exception object will be created and most likely java will do some logging of the event, so your better of just using an if statement.

Comment: C#, not Java, but the same automatic logging could apply depending on the specifics of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Using the catch block in the way you described in your question is a bad idea. Try-catch blocks themselves do not have a huge performance impact, but exceptions do have a large performance cost.

The best option is to use the `TryParse` method on the float class instead. There is a reason it exists.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Rico Mariani has the last word, as usual:

[The True Cost of .NET Exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/09/25/771142.aspx)

Yes, using a Try/Catch block is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar enough with the intricacies of c# to tell you whether an if, or a tryparse statement or a try catch are going to be faster. What I can offer you is the idea of thinking about calls.

If you're worried about performance on something as simple as implementation of the same process, think about the number of calls as well. If you check every single number if it's 0, or call try-parse on every single number then you're adding that call to every iteration, not just the iterations that fail. If this implementation works for you, it is a good approach as it only gets into the catch block when it fails.

For many programs, this sort of implementation wouldn't work, because they want to do additional processing in the catch block. For those programs, you'd want to check for the 0, or do the tryparse. Since you're just returning, I believe this makes for easily readable code.